# Microsoft SQL Database Seed data into table pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines, azure-sql-server

I am a bit struggling to find the best approach to achieve this.

I am trying to achieve a full automated process to spin up a Microsoft sql server, a SQL Database using terraform, and ultimately, when I have all the infra in place, to release a `*.dacpac` against the SQL Database to create tables and column and ultimately seed some data inside this database.

So far I am using azure pipeline to achieve this and this is my workflow:

- terraform init
- terraform validate
- terraform apply
- database script (to create the tables and script

The above steps works just fine and everything falls in place perfectly. Now I would like to implement another step to seed the database from a `csv` or `excel`.

A did some research on google and read Microsoft Documentation but apparently there are different ways of doing this but all those approaches, from `bulk insert` to `bcp sqlcmd`, are documented with a local server and not a cloud server.

Can anyone please advice me about how to achieve this task using azure pipeline and a cloud SQL Database? Thank you so so much for any hint

UPDATE:
If I create a task in release pipeline for cmd script. I get the following error:

```
2021-11-12T17:38:39.1887476Z Generating script.
2021-11-12T17:38:39.2119542Z Script contents:
2021-11-12T17:38:39.2146058Z bcp Company in "./Company.csv" -c -t -S XXXXX -d XXXX -U usertest -P ***
2021-11-12T17:38:39.2885488Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2021-11-12T17:38:39.3505412Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\33c62204-f40c-4662-afb8-862bbd4c42b5.cmd""
2021-11-12T17:38:39.7265213Z SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
2021-11-12T17:38:39.7266751Z Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be actually [quite simple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15):

> The following example imports data using Azure AD Username and Password where user and password is an AAD credential. The example imports data from file c:\last\data1.dat into table bcptest for database testdb on Azure server aadserver.database.windows.net using Azure AD User/Password:

```
bcp bcptest in "c:\last\data1.dat" -c -t -S aadserver.database.windows.net -d testdb -G -U alice@aadtest.onmicrosoft.com -P xxxxx
```

If you do not plan use AAD account - please remove `-G` flag.

Ideally it would be if you put your admin account name and password into terraform directly from terraform. The you can fetch those values vie KeyVault task in the pipeline and use to run above mentioned script.

It looks that bcp is already on windows agents:

[image]

Comment: I presume the pipeline would be an inline script, to install mssql and bcp and run the command? There is one thing that confuses me here. As this would be a task in the pipeline, I presume the path to the file, will be the one in the repo right?

Comment: bcp is already on windows agents. And yes path to the file should be the one to repo (in this case please make sure your job checkouted repo), or you can publish your file as an artifact and then download it on the job where you want to seed database.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I just updated my post with the issue I am facing.